# Picture Will Not Fill Bounds with Theoretical Max

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, bounds

I am creating a game and I need to put in a picture in that will fill the screens x-coordinate bounds and go partially up in the y direction. I am testing it on the iPhone 6s plus emulator on Xcode. I believe I am running the correct method to get the x-coordinate size of the screen. However, when I specify that I want the size of the node containing the picture to be the same as the height, x-coordinate direction (because my game will only be played in portrait only), and i center it, the node resizes to fit almost all the way on both sides in the x direction, but leaves a little white space on either side. I hard coded the values displayed by putting the printed values from

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/width
```

into

```
mynode.size.height/width
```

thereby testing both dimensions, and it still left space on each of the four sides. Does Apple automatically leave space in all four directions between the theoretical bounds of the screen and the actual edge?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to map the coordinates of the SKScene to those of the frame. I accomplished this by changing the scene scale mode to resizefill in the view controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```